# How do I remove Trojan horse virus from my android smartphone?

Tags: applications, security, usb-debugging, malware

There is a virus in my android phone named `com.wgjvp.idck` and I tried every possible solution to remove it but couldn't find any solution. 
What I did:

1. I hard-reset(factory-reset) my phone twice but this virus suddenly comes out.
2. Installed `Security-Master` but that also unable to resolve this
   problem

This virus creates a pop-up over ads due to which I am unable to perform anything.
Even after successfully `uninstalling` this app when I lock it and open it, this virus is present already.

Two things takes place:

1. After `uninstalling' this app, it automatically gets installed.
   And
2. USB-Debugging gets checked every time automatically.

This virus also switches-off the phone at certain interval. In setting inside apps virus name displayed as `com.wgjvp.idck` though on home screen the name is `Nolcans`.

I think possible solution could be disabling the developer option permanently or doing something due to which it should not be easily gets checked. and second is to block a particular app from installing in my phone with particular bundle-id or app-id like `com.abc.xyz` but I don't know how to do that.

So what should I do to completely remove this Trojan horse virus from my phone? Thanks!

Comment: Please see the malware tag wiki (tag added to your question) for help. As suggested in the answer by Kwon, that is the last resort if nothing else works

Comment: Do you mind sharing which make and model your phone is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-flash the firmware. I recommend it especially when encountering malwares and such.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But can this be removed without re-flashing? Any other possible solution to this problem? Will rooting my phone work?

Comment: Nah man, some antivirus will just tell you it deletes the virus but it only pushes some adwares into your system

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the virus has violated the boot area of ​​the smartphone. It seems that treatment is difficult in factory initialization. Therefore, you need to directly download the new genuine official firmware and reinstall the firmware.

All data is deleted, you can install genuine firmware and return all things to the initial state.

Even though one can do it without difficulty, in case it is difficult get the help of the official repair center.

Comment: Are you saying to flash `ROM` of my phone?

Comment: A few more questions, if you concede: are you sure that's the "boot" area the one violated by the "virus"? Since the asker didn't specify their phone model, how can you be certain that the official firmware doesn't come with bundled malware?